# Convert an Exact-Rational to an Integer in Racket

Tags: types, integer, typeerror, racket, typed-racket

I am writing a function in `typed/racket` to convert a list of `Integers` (0 or 1) representing a hexadecimal value to a decimal (`Integer`).

The function :

```racket
#lang typed/racket
(: to-decimal (-> (Listof Integer) Integer))
(define (to-decimal hex-values)
  (for/fold
          ([index : Integer 0]
           [result : Integer 0]
           #:result result)
          ([v : Integer (reverse hex-values)])
          (values (add1 index) (+ result (* v (expt 2 index))))))
```

This fails to type check. The expression `(+ result (* v (expt 2 index)))` gives me this error `type mismatch expected: Integer given: Exact-Rational`.

I know that Integers are a subset of Exact-Rational ([source](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html)). Is there any way I can make my code type check ? Maybe by converting the value returned by the failing expression to `Integer` ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

(I share the answer that I found)

As `index` as been marked as `Integer`, it can be either positive, null or negative integer. As a consequence,`(expt 2 index)` can return a rational (if `index` is negative for example).

If `index` is marked as a `Nonnegative-Integer`, the function type check.